# Python Package for Gender Detection by First Name

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

What is the best Python package for gender detection using name?

Answer (score 1):

@Alireza Javadian, This may be help you -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-gender-identification-by-name-using-nltk/